# MVC 2 Asp.net C# code for drop down list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

hey i was looking out for a code to make a drop down list to take a value from the user, refer it to the database and retrieve database table values. I'm a newbie at C# and would really use some help.

Comment: This is very similar to using a textbox, except a select list is just limiting what the user can specify. What you want to do can be found in just about any beginner MVC tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of resources for this situation. Here are a few: [1](http://iainjmitchell.com/blog/?p=321), [2](http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/rendering-and-binding-drop-down-lists-using-asp-net-mvc-2-editorfor/), and [3](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/18/drop-down-lists-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx)
Those are just 3. A google search will turn up a lot more.